# How to keep iterating ArrayList as you remove objects from it

Tags: java, arraylist

In hopes of trying to implement the Banker's algorithm in Java I am attempting to iterate through an ArrayList that stores the id of a number of threads. I want to keep iterating through this array until I have found a safe sequence (or not). So far, I am able to iterate through the ArrayList only once, but I need to remove objects as iterate if I found that they are next in my safe sequence.

How do I keep iterating through an ArrayList (or any other data structure) in a circular fashion as I remove objects from it as I go? I hope my question is clear enough, but here is what I have so far:
In the best case, the algorithm stops when there are 0 objects left in the list.

**EDIT**
What I mean by circular fashion is this: 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4 (also I need to be able to remove processes from the list, so the iterations should become smaller.) might look something like: Note that the algo stops when there are 0 in the list remaining

0,1,2,3,4

,0,2,3,4

2,3,4

2,4

4

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
            Integer thisOne = it.next();
            found=false;
            // this process, can be removed from the list
            // because cN = its current need
            // a = how much the process is allocated already
            // cR=bank's current resources
            // so if cN - a <= cR, we know there is no deficit
            // we can satisfy this process, and remove it from the list 
            // of needy processes

            if(noDeficit(cN[thisOne], a[thisOne], cR)){

                // we take away its resources and give them to the bank
                Utility.add(cR, a[thisOne]);
                Utility.zeroOut(cN[thisOne]);
                Utility.zeroOut(a[thisOne]);

                found = true;
                // we remove it from the list of processes 
                it.remove();                                    
            }if(!found) return false;

        }
```

Comment: `if(!found) return false;` means that you'll keep removing the first value from the list until `noDeficit()` returns false, at which point you stop. Is that your intention?

Comment: This is very difficult to follow without more context. What collection are you iterating over? How does it relate to `cN`, `a`, `cR`? What are all those `Utility` methods for?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a circular fashion"?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question fully, but if there is noDeficit, I can allow the process to finish, so I can remove it from the list and stop iterating through it in the future. If found is never true, is a way of breaking out of the while loop because there might not be a safe sequence at all.

Comment: I will add more comments guys!

Comment: I hope that is more clear.

Comment: Please edit your own question for clarification.

Comment: There you go. I am not sure if I am making sense.

Comment: `found=false; if(noDeficit()) { found=true; remove(); } if(!found) return false;` is the *same* as `if (! noDeficit()) { return false; } remove();`. As I said you either remove the first value (repeatedly), or you stop. You will never look at any value after a value you didn't remove.

Answer (score 0):

Not really getting what your "found" condition should do, but here's an approach.

```
    //todo  create loop condition for stopping, eg originalList.size() > 0
    //eg
    List<Integer> itemsToRemoveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (originalList.size() > 0) { 
       Iterator it = originalList.iterator();      

       while (it.hasNext()) {
          Integer thisOne = it.next();
          found=false;
          // this process, can be removed from the list
          if(noDeficit(cN[thisOne], a[thisOne], cR)){

              // we take away its resources and give them to the bank
              Utility.add(cR, a[thisOne]);
              Utility.zeroOut(cN[thisOne]);
              Utility.zeroOut(a[thisOne]);

              // we remove it from the list of processes 
              itemsToRemoveList.add(thisOne);
           }                                   
        } //end loop

        for (Integer integerToRemove : itemsToRemoveList) {  
           originalList.remove(integerToRemove);
        }
        itemsToRemoveList.clear();

   }
```

Comment: What I am concerned with is the fact that the since noDeficit() may never be satisfied, how would the loop break?

Comment: This actually seems very helpful, so I will give it a try. Thank you ahead of time. I will make sure to mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: @RománMaksimov - since I wasn't for sure how you entered this method, I left it a general approach. But yes, you could use your found flag to control the loop as well. In fact, if you only need to go through this one time you can remove the outer loop entirely. Just iterate and then when done, remove any of the elements that are in the itemsToRemoveList and exit the method. If no elements are in that list, none were "found" ... good luck.